# Kotlin Serialization is not applied to the module

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

In my project I need to use Kotlin.Serialization, so by documenting myself I saw how to import the plugin.

In the `build.gradle(project)` here is the `plugins` block.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.48.1' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.5.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.9.20'

}
```

In the `build.gradle(app)` here is the plugins block:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}
```

And there I implement the following library:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.0"
```

The problem is, annotating the following class with `@Serializable` like this:

```
@Serializable
data class User(
    val name: String = "",
    val surname: String = "",
    val phone: String = "",
    val email: String = "",
)
```

Android studio leaves me with this warning:

> kotlinx.serialization compiler plugin is not applied to the module,
> so this annotation would not be processed.

I poked around StackOverflow and noticed that the code in the `build.gradle` is correct, so I really wouldn't know how to fix this warning.

Comment: Apart from the inspection warning, does your code work? Can you serialize/deserialize `User`?

Comment: No my code doesn't work because I need the function 'serializer()'

Comment: I have the same warning, but deserialization works fine for me. It's possible that this warning is a distraction and that your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: the object to which I affix the Serializable annotation does not generate a method called serializer() precisely because the annotation has that warning. So the annotation doesn't generate the necessary code

Comment: When I remove either `@Serializable` or `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'`, the code stops working. So the plugin is definitely getting applied. `MySerializable.serializer()` is missing, as you  report, but I can write `val serializer = serializer<MySerializable>()` and that works. This function isn't generated, it's present in `Serializers.kt`. I think this is a reasonable workaround. Or you may try to downgrade the plugin, since this seems like a bug.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I have a similar situation, except not directly calling `.serializer()` in my code (instead, I'm using `kotlinx.serialization.json.Json` encode/decode methods). I just tried downgrading the plugin to 7 different older versions, with the exact same results. Maybe I just don't know which version to downgrade it to, or maybe something else is going on.

Comment: ...and by also downgrading kotlin-stdlib now I see the same situation as you, @MarkoTopolnik, where it shows the warning but everything works again.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a bug in this version of the serialization plugin. Even though the plugin is getting applied and the serializers get registered, the function `MySerializable.serializer()` is missing. A workaround is to use the function `kotlinx.serialization.serializer<MySerializable>()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your project level build.gradle

```
plugins {
     id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.9.20' apply false
}
```

That might be the problem.

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve the warning

Answer (score 0):

I see you forgot to add this to `build.gradle(app)`.

```
plugins {
    ...    
    id 'kotlinx-serialization'
    ...
}
```

Comment: This advice seems to contradict the documentation. Can you add an official documentation link where this plugin ID is mentioned?

Comment: In fact, the documentation talks about this plugin     id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization', But I've also tried the one recommended and it doesn't solve

Comment: Thank you for your return. I use it in my own project, additionally I reviewed the other answers given. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54780989/5595926

Comment: It seems to have been this way in an early version of the plugin (year is 2019).

Comment: Even the mentioned answer does not solve the problem (moreover, an answer I already consulted before asking the question.)